# What does =& mean in PHP?

Tags: php

Consider:

```
$smarty =& SESmarty::getInstance();
```

What is the `&` for?

Comment: If you need something like this in the future search for "operators" in the PHP help references, or a good search engine.

Comment: You should also look up something called "Singleton".

Comment: `=&` is not "a thing" -- it is two things that should not be smooshed together.  See the explanation in this post for the reasons that you should not be writing `=&`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It passes by reference. Meaning that it won't create a copy of the value passed.

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php (See Adam's Answer)

Usually, if you pass something like this:

```
$a = 5;
$b = $a;
$b = 3;

echo $a; // 5
echo $b; // 3
```

The original variable (`$a`) won't be modified if you change the second variable (`$b`) . If you pass by reference:

```
$a = 5;
$b =& $a;
$b = 3;

echo $a; // 3
echo $b; // 3
```

The original is changed as well.

Which is useless when passing around objects, because they will be passed by reference by default.

Comment: In addition to what Chacha102 said, from the manual: > References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by different names. The manual section is at http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: PHP5 objects are *not* passed by reference by default: rather, an object identifier is passed by value (similar to Java's 'reference' semantics); see the manual for details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: It really is kind of pointless. The main reason people used them was to not require a function to return a variable, but instead just have to modify the variable.

Comment: @Chacha102 and @jasondavis References are ABSOLUTELY not pointless.  They are invaluable.  Perhaps they are not always useful when working with primitives, but they are incredibly useful when working with ANY OOP -- including basic arrays.

Comment: Oh, and they make the Singleton POSSIBLE.

Answer (score 8):

In PHP 4, it kind of (awkwardly) associated two variables.

```
$j = 'original';
$i =& $j;
$i = 'modified';
echo $j; // The output is 'modified'
```

Likewise...

```
$j = 'original';
$i =& $j;
$j = 'modified';
echo $i; // The output is 'modified'
```

Some of this was made a little less unpleasant when it comes to objects in [PHP 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history), but I think the heart of it is the same, so these examples should still be valid.

Answer (score 1):

[References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) are used to alias variables and were necessary to use the old object system efficiently.

In PHP 4, objects behaved like any other value type, that is, assignment would create a copy of the object. If you wanted to avoid this, you had to use a reference as in your example code.

With [PHP 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history), object variables no longer contain the object itself, but a handle (AKA object identifier) and assignment will only copy the handle. Using a reference is no longer necessary.