# Why should I need "&"?

Tags: php, oop

See example on the web about the PHP Factory Pattern.

In the line `$kind =& Vehicle::category($wheel);`, why should I to use `&`?

The code:

```
<?php
    class Vehicle {

        function category($wheel = 0) {
            if ($wheel == 2) {
                return "Motor";
            } elseif($wheel == 4) {
                return "Car";
            }
        }
    }

    class Spec {

        var $wheel = '';

        function Spec($wheel) {
            $this->wheel = $wheel;
        }

        function name() {
            $wheel = $this->wheel;
                return Vehicle::category($wheel);
        }

        function brand() {
            $wheel = $this->wheel;
                $kind =& Vehicle::category($wheel);
            if ($kind == "Motor") {
                return array('Harley','Honda');
            } elseif($kind = "Car") {
                return array('Nisan','Opel');
            }
        }
    }

    $kind = new Spec(2);
    echo "Kind: ".$kind->name();
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Brand: " . implode(",", $kind->brand());
?>
```

Comment: Warning: the line `}elseif($kind = "Car"){` needs `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: I don't see that untill you posted Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is useless here since the example is getting a reference to a constant, but [references](http://php.net/references) do have their uses when you want to "watch" a value that might change, and you want your variable to change with it.

Answer (score 5):

From Stack Overflow question *[Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139)*:

`=&` References

- *[Reference assignment operator in PHP, =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343)*
- *[What do the "=&" and "&=" operators in PHP mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454)*
- *[What do the '&=' and '=&' operators do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177342)*
- *[What does =& mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081806)*

As the (deleted) comment said, the last link should apply to your specific case.